# Using SQLite with HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite

I am trying to learn how to use `SQLite` with `HTML5` and I am reading and watching some tutorials. I am confused about one thing nobody really explained, where is the database created? I got this sample code from one of the tutorials I watched and he said where to find the database, but since it was an older video I don't think the place he told me is correct anymore.

Link to the code: [Link](http://revenmerchantservices.com/post/HTML5-With-DataBase.aspx)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Button1").click(function() {
                var database = openDatabase($("#Text1").val(), "1.0", "Contact Manager", 200000);

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span>Enter DataBase Name: <input id="Text1" type="text" /></span>
    <span> 
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Create DataBase" /></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Can somebody explain/tell me where the database file was created and stored?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Thunderbird/HowTos/Common_Thunderbird_Extension_Techniques/Use_SQLite

Comment: From your very own link that contains the code: `Above code snippets creates ContactManager at client browser. If it is created in Chrome browser, only chrome can access this database. Other browsers will not be able to access that database.` The other way you can do it is to use sqlite on the server, interacting with the database with server-side scripts, rather than client-side ones. You can copy/backup/delete this file just like any other. I pull the sqLite db from my Android phone and look at it with php. It gives me millisecond time-stamps and call durations.